# Slow down the water ceramic dispenser for plant

Tags: watering

I bought this ceramic water dispenser for my indoor plant. It is working fine, except for it provides too much water than the plant needs. Thus the excess amount of water just spilling on the floor.

Is there a way I can slow down the process?

Thank you.

[image: Water dispenser]

[image: My setup]

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this video https://youtu.be/iCY7j3olaPc

Your water level is higher than the soil, and now the system works on gravity rather than capillary. Use capillary action by lowering the water level or the container.